# EF Core multiple references to same table with circullar reference

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have looked through related posts but I still can not figure out what should be the right solution for my issue.
I am creating database structure for user messaging application.
My idea for the schema was as follows:
User has many Conversations and Messages
Conversation has 2 Users and many Messages
Message has 1 User and 1 Conversation

I have 3 tables:

```
public class UserEntity : IEntity
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
 
    public ICollection<ConversationEntity> Conversations { get; set; }
    public ICollection<MessageEntity> Messages { get; set; }
}

public class MessageEntity : IEntity
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string Content { get; set; }

    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
    public UserEntity User { get; set; }

    public Guid ConversationId { get; set; }
    public ConversationEntity Conversation { get; set; }
}

public class ConversationEntity : IEntity
  {
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public Guid UserOneId { get; set; }
    public UserEntity UserOne { get; set; }

    public Guid UserTwoId { get; set; }
    public UserEntity UserTwo { get; set; }
    public ICollection<MessageEntity> Messages { get; set; }
}
```

And this is the way how I am configuring those tables:

```
public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<UserEntity> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("Users");
        builder.HasKey(x => x.Id);
        builder.Property(x => x.Id).ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
    }

public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<MessageEntity> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("Messages");
        builder.HasKey(x => x.Id);
        builder.Property(x => x.Id).ValueGeneratedOnAdd();

        builder.HasOne(x => x.Conversation)
            .WithMany(x => x.Messages)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.ConversationId);

        builder.HasOne(x => x.User)
            .WithMany(x => x.Messages)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.UserId);
    }

        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<ConversationEntity> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("Conversations");
        builder.HasKey(x => x.Id);
        builder.Property(x => x.Id).ValueGeneratedOnAdd();

        builder.HasOne(x => x.UserOne)
          .WithMany()
          .HasForeignKey(x => x.UserOneId)
          .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);

        builder.HasOne(x => x.UserTwo)
          .WithMany()
          .HasForeignKey(x => x.UserTwoId)
          .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);
    }
```

Now I have two issues:

1. Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_Conversations_Users_UserTwoId' on table 'Conversations' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
2. How can I rollback the applied changes? Some of the has been applied to database (I have checked and the conversation table has been generated) and the relations also has been created in a very weird way:
   [image]

Can I please receive help how to rollback this? I tried applying earlier migration but this did not work (Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_Conversations_Users_UserTwoId' on table 'Conversations' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
Could not create constraint. See previous errors.)

[EDIT]:
I have tested the solution and I have recreated the whole database, what is interesting this error is not happening any longer, however in the Keys folder of Conversations table i Can see this:
[image]

Why there is this "FK_Conversations_Users_UserEntityId"  ??

Comment: I believe there's some PM command like `Remove-Migration` or `Delete-Migration` which would delete the migration and then you could just `Update-Database` to rollback to the previous migration. Unrelated, what software did you use to get the image?

Comment: Those commands are failing :) software for capturing the screen: https://getgreenshot.org/ software for generating this diagram: Built-in diagram generator in SQL Server Management Studio

Comment: @RoyCohen: Not OP, but Windows has a built-in screenshot tool. Search for "snipping tool" in the start menu. It's not the fanciest screenshot tool (Greenshot definitely has more features) but it is capable of taking click-and-drag screenshots like the one in this question.

Comment: I have a suggestion but I'm not sure it'll work. Maybe instead of having every conversation with two user property navigation properties, have every conversation with a single collection navigation property. That way the user-conversation relationship would be a simple many-to-many relationship. The downside is that it's not guaranteed that every conversation would have exactly two users and you have to watch out for that.

Comment: @RoyCohen so User would have collection of conversation and conversation would have a collection of users? and then conversation would have a collection of messages, each message reference to user; user table shall also have a collection of messages? (circullar references)

Comment: @Eru Well of course there's gonna be circullar references. As long as a user has a reference to its conversation, a conversation has a refernce to its messages, and a message has a reference to its user, there's ganna be a circullar reference. There's no way around this. But why is that a problem?

Comment: @RoyCohen when I'm running update-database with that new migration it tells me that there is a circular reference and it fails

Comment: I was also thinking about actually removing the connection betwenn user and messsage - just have the column for user ID, but without actual relationship.

Comment: @RoyCohen I have added an edit to the main post. why there is this fk for UserEntityId ? what the hell is this?

Comment: @Eru How did you test the solution? Did you add records and manipulated them to confirm that the solution works? From my personal experiance I can tell you that sometimes it looks like it works but it doesn't. Regarding `UserEntityId`, I don't know what that is.

Comment: @RoyCohen by "test" I have run the scripts again - removed all migrations files etc, deleted the database, created new one, created new init migration and applied that to the database

Comment: @Eru I suggest you try adding entities to your tables and check that the navigation properties are working.

Comment: @RoyCohen I have just started that :)

Comment: @RoyCohen I was able to add messages and conversations and it looks like this is working for me good enough. I am not sure about those navigation properties for now. However you can try to post an answer and I will accept it as answer - later on if I find problem with loding navigation properties I will reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify the relationship between the users and the conversations by having it as a regular many-to-many relationship. The downside is that *you* need to inforce the rule that every conversation must have two users.
In order to try to minimize the change, properties can be written to replace the old `UserOne` and `UserTwo` properties:

```cs
public UserEntity UserOne
{
    get => Users[0];
    set => Users[0] = value;
}
```

(`Users` is the new collection navigation property added to `ConversationEntity`)

Comment: thank you for the reply and help in the comments:)

Answer (score 1):

For the second point if you are on .NET Frameework 4.x open `Tools -> Nuget Package Manager -> Package Manager Console` under project tab select the project that contains the migrations folder and in the command line type `Update-Database -TargetMigration:"NameOfMigrationYouWantToRollbackTo" -Force`. If you use ASP.NET CORE/.NET Core  open `Tools -> Nuget Package Manager -> Package Manager Console` under the project tab select the project that contains the migrations folder and type `Remove-Migration` to remove the last migration and after that `Update-Database` to rollback the database. If you want to remove two or more migrations just repeat the process.